# Show $\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac {x dx}{(a^2\sin^2 x+ b^2\cos^2 x)^{2}}=\frac {\pi^2 (a^2+b^2)}{4a^3b^3}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Show that

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac {x dx}{(a^2\sin^2 x+ b^2\cos^2 x)^{2}}=\frac {\pi^2 (a^2+b^2)}{4a^3b^3}$$

My Attempt:

Let $$I=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac {x dx}{(a^2\sin^2 x+b^2 \cos^2 x)^2} $$
Using $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx=\int_{a}^{b} f(a+b-x)dx$ we can write:

$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac {(\pi - x)dx}{(a^2\sin^2 x+b^2\cos^2 x)^2} $$
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac {\pi dx}{(a^2\sin^2 x+b^2\cos^2 x)^2} - \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac {x dx}{(a^2\sin^2 x+b^2\cos^2 x)^2}$$
$$I=2\pi \int_{0}^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \frac {dx}{(a^2\sin^2 x+b^2\cos^2 x)^2} - I$$
$$I=\pi \int_{0}^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \frac {dx}{(a^2\sin^2 x+b^2 \cos^2 x)^2} $$

Comment: Please articulate what your question is?

Comment: @amWhy, Proving the required.

Comment: That's not a question.  That's a command, or a statement "I was asked to prove this... here's my incomplete work".  Are you implying that you are instructing us to prove it for you, or do you have a question about where you are stuck, or about the correctness of your work so far, or both?  If so, ***say so in an edit in your question body***, not in comments.

Comment: Gentle suggestion: I'd recommend phrasing this in terms of "what techniques of integration are needed to perform this integral?"  Have you tried trig substitutions, or rearranging the problem in any meaningful way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x dx}{(a^2 \sin^2 x+ b^2 \cos^2x)^2}~~~(1)$$
Apply $\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx=\int_{0}^{a} f(a-x) dx$.
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{(\pi-x) dx}{(a^2 \sin^2 x+ b^2 \cos^2x)^2}~~~(2)$$
Add (1) and (2)
$$2I=\pi\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{ dx}{(a^2 \sin^2 x+ b^2 \cos^2x)^2}~~~(3)$$
Use $\int_{0}^{2a} f(x) dx=\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx, ~if ~f(2a-x)=f(x)$
$$I=\pi \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{(a^2 \sin^2 x+ b^2 \cos^2x)^2}~~~(4)$$
Let $$J(a,b)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{(a^2 \sin^2 x+ b^2 \cos^2x)}=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} 
\frac {\sec^2 x dx}{b^2+a^2\tan^2 x} =\frac{\pi}{2ab}~~~(5)$$
D. (5) w.r.t. $a$ to get
$$\frac{J(a,b)}{da}=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{-2a \sin^2 xdx}{(a^2 \sin^2 x+ b^2 \cos^2x)^2}=-\frac{\pi}{2a^2b}~~~~(6)$$
$$\implies \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin^2x dx}{(a^2 \sin^2 x+ b^2 \cos^2x)^2}=\frac{\pi}{4a^3b}~~~(7)$$
Similarly by D.w.r.t. $b$, we can get
$$\implies \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos^2x dx}{(a^2 \sin^2 x+ b^2 \cos^2x)^2}=\frac{\pi}{4a^3b}~~~(8)$$
Adding (7) and (8), we get from (4)
$$I=\frac{\pi^2}{4}\frac{a^2+b^2}{a^3b^2}.$$

Comment: Due to copy-pasting, you keep writing $\cos^x$ instead of $\cos^2x$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

Continue with the substitution $t=\tan x$,

$$\begin{align}
& \pi \int_{0}^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \frac {dx}{(a^2\sin^2 x+b^2 \cos^2 x)^2} \\
 & = \pi \int_0^\infty \frac{1+t^2}{(b^2+a^2t^2)^2}dt \\
&=\frac{\pi(a^2-b^2)}{2a^2b^2} \frac t {b^2+a^2t^2}\bigg|_ 0^\infty
 + \frac{\pi(a^2+b^2)}{2a^2b^2} \int_0^\infty \frac {dt}{b^2+a^2t^2} \\
& =0+\frac{\pi(a^2+b^2)}{2a^3b^3} \tan^{-1}\frac {at}b\bigg|_0^\infty \\
&=\frac{\pi^2(a^2+b^2)}{4a^3b^3}\\
\end{align}$$